# Adb does not see any installed device after Android Studio update

Tags: android, adb

I have updated my Android Studio from v.0.6.1 to v.0.8.1.

Now adb cannot see my physical devices although the driver is installed properly (see screenshot)

[image: Device manager]

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

Comment: Try adb kill-server, and adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

When I reinstall IDE completely, I always have to edit ~/.android/android_usb.ini to add my devices USB VENDOR ID

Comment: In my case this file contains one line: `# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.` I tried to use `android update adb`, it writes that adb is updated but I don't see any changes in this file. Devices are still invisible.

Comment: Look at details on Android Composite ADB Interface and find line like this: USB\Vid_2717&Pid_904e&Rev_0228&MI_01. You see Vid_2717? In that case you must add to adb_usb.ini line 0x2717

Comment: I have added vendor ID and restarted adb. No effect (

Answer (score 0):

Double check there are no updates required within the SDK Manager. If not, then go to Android Studio and then on the menu go to Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration.

Also from the command line run adb devices and ensure that the device is listed there. I don't know what version of Android you have, but make sure USB debugging is turned on and I think since Jelly Bean a popup should appear on screen asking you to confirm that you want to allow the device to connect to the PC.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ADB integration is enabled but it has no effect. USB debugging is turned on, but device is absent in device list (

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your device, I've sometimes needed to do that before it will see it, occasionally PC as well, but normally a device reboot resolves it

Comment: Turned on "USB Debugging" is crucial. Sometimes after reboot, especially if I update my ROM, this option will be disabled by system.

Answer (score 0):

This is not AS problem. Try in terminal

adb kill-server

adb start-server